# Changing date format in SQL Select Statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, date-formatting

Hi I have written a query to extract the create date and I would like the output to be YYYYMM. However, the existing format in the database returns YYMM. How do I do the conversion? I have tried to run the code below and it returns an error saying that I have a missing expression.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(6,[CREATED_DATE], 120) as 'CREATED_DATE' 
FROM SGTEL10.B$GC_NETELEM
WHERE IPID IN (4001702, 4006023, 4320791);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using format mask `112`, with a `varchar(6)` (i.e. 6 characters wide):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), GETDATE(), 112);
```

This outputs:

```
201904
```

Your full updated query:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),[CREATED_DATE], 112) AS [CREATED_DATE]
FROM SGTEL10.B$GC_NETELEM
WHERE IPID IN (4001702, 4006023, 4320791);
```

[Tech on the Net](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/convert.php) is my favorite reference for looking up the SQL Server `CONVERT` format masks.

Comment: :)  just very close... I am removing my answer :)

Comment: Hi. I have just tried what you've suggested but it returns the same error. I would like to check if the getdate that you have indicated refers to the "created date" column in my code?

Comment: @Samuel You are missing a closing parenthesis after `VARCHAR(6`.  Fix that, and the error should go away.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server: use the [`FORMAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function to format dates:

```
SELECT FORMAT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'yyyyMM')
-- 201904
```

PL/SQL: use [`TO_CHAR`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm) function:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'YYYYMM') FROM DUAL
-- 201904
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? You need to replace `GETDATE()` with the coumn name though.

Comment: i'm using SQL PL:D

Comment: See revised answer

Answer (score 0):

SELECT convert(nvarchar(10), datepart(year,getdate ())) + ' ' + convert(nvarchar(10), datepart(month,getdate ()))

Comment: replace getdate () with created_date